# Upload PDF file in JSP page and convert it to text file

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, text

I need some help with my code.. I have a working Java code to convert PDF to Text file and a JSP page which uploads it.
The thing is I want to link them i.e., when I upload a PDF file it should take the file uploaded as input and generate corresponding converted text file.

```
    FileConverter.java

    package fileconverter;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
    import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

    public class FileConverter {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
      selectPDFFiles();

    }
      //allow pdf files selection for converting
      public static void selectPDFFiles(){

      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
      FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PDF","pdf");
      chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
      chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
      int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
      if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
           File[] Files=chooser.getSelectedFiles();
           System.out.println("Please wait...");
           for( int i=0;i<Files.length;i++){     
            convertPDFToText(Files[i].toString(),"Text-File"+i+".txt");

             }
             System.out.println("Conversion complete");

            }


        }

         public static void convertPDFToText(String src,String desc){
            try{
         FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(desc);
         try (
           BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
          PdfReader pr=new PdfReader(src);              
          int pNum=pr.getNumberOfPages();              
           for(int page=1;page<=pNum;page++){
            String text=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pr, page);
            bw.write(text);
            bw.newLine();

            }
           bw.flush();
          }

         }
          catch(IOException e){}

           }

         }



         upload.jsp
            <%-- 
                Document   : upload
                Created on : May 16, 2014, 1:42:47 PM
                Author     : Kelvin
            --%>

            <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
               <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            </head><title>Upload and convert</title>
            <body>
             <div id="main">
               <table id="uploadtbl" width="550" align="center" border="1">
               <tr>
                 <th align="center">Upload and convert pdf to text file</th>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td>
                     <input type="file" name="upload">
                 </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td><input type="submit" name="totext" value="Convert To Text" /></td>
               </tr>
             </table>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: And what's your problem?

Comment: Thank you AlexR, my problem here is I don't know how to link the Java program and the JSP page such that when I click on the submit button , to convert the uploaded pdf file into a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you have to create HTML form that sends file to your server using POST method, i.e. something like this:

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
<form>
```

Now you need server side. You can implement your own servlet (or JSP although it is not recommended to implement code into JSP) and deploy it under URL `"/upload"`. The name of URL does not matter, it just must correspond to what you write in `action` attribute of your form.

However you do not have to implement servlet. Just take it from [apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html). I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to implement a servlet at first using the above Java code but failed because I'm still new to servlets. Can u please show me some tips on how to implement a servlet of such kind sir.

Comment: Again, you do not have to implement anything. Just deploy the `FileUpload` servlet from Apache on your container. Please follow the link I provided. Here it is again: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/using.html

Comment: Still new here with few "reputation" not enough to Vote up but your help is really appreciated. Thank you once more sir